# HtmlWebpackPlugin not minifying script tag

Tags: webpack, minify, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) with these settings:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.ejs',
    minify: isDevelopment ? false : {
        caseSensitive: false,
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: false,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: false,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
        sortAttributes: true,
        sortClassName: true,
    },
}),
```

which I believe are forwarded to [html-minifier-terser](https://github.com/DanielRuf/html-minifier-terser), but it's not compressing my `<script>` tag.

The HTML and CSS are compacted, but not my JS.

How can I enable script compression?

---

Not completely true actually, I'm not sure what it's doing. This:

```html
    <script>
        // TODO: compress this or move this or something
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                // https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
                    console.info('SW registered: ', registration);
                }).catch(registrationError => {
                    console.error('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

"Compresses" to this:

```html
<script>// TODO: compress this or move this or something
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                // https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
                    console.info('SW registered: ', registration);
                }).catch(registrationError => {
                    console.error('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
                });
            });
        }</script>
```

i.e., it removed a little bit of whitespace, which might even just be from the `collapseWhitespace` option. However, this:

```html
<script>if('serviceWorker' in navigator)navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')</script>
```

Will compress to:

```html
<script>"serviceWorker"in navigator&&navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js")</script>
```

So it *is* doing something, but I don't know what. Does it not like when I have comments in there?

Comment: HtmlWebpackPlugin uses another plugin [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options). If you use `minifyJS: true` then too aggressive approach to js compression :)
Change to it: `minifyJS: { compress: { conditionals: false  }}` You can always check the settings online - [terser-online](https://xem.github.io/terser-online/)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. It's not too aggressive, it's just ignoring the code in my first example. If I paste it into that terser-online it compresses fine.

Answer (score 3):

`collapseWhitespace: true` works only on html does not work significantly on JS. Take a look here [collapse_whitespace](http://perfectionkills.com/experimenting-with-html-minifier/#collapse_whitespace)

I tested your case, only that I changed minifyJS to the one below. And everything has been compressed nicely, even the script in html

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.ejs',
  minify: isDevelopment ? false : {
    caseSensitive: false,
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    useShortDoctype: false,
    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
    keepClosingSlash: false,
    minifyJS: { compress: { conditionals: false }}
    minifyCSS: true,
    minifyURLs: true,
    sortAttributes: true,
    sortClassName: true,
  },
}),
```

But if `minifyJS: true` then the code breaks like you do
The problem is `minifyJS: true` which interferes too much with the script. Take a look how many options are there and it's just compression, insanity [compress-options](https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options) :)

I never compress html script myself for the simple reason that there are too many problems with it. I always set `minify: true` which in default gives us:

```
{
   collapseWhitespace: true,
   removeComments: true,
   removeRedundantAttributes: true,
   removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
   removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
   useShortDoctype: true
}
```

Comment: `minify: true` doesn't seem to do anything at all. I think there's a bug in here somewhere; it won't compress my script if it contains arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a bug somewhere; it won't compress the script if it contains arrow functions (I think that's the deciding factor -- it minified as soon as I took them out). I tried playing with the `parse` options which you can pass through to [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) but that didn't help.

Turns out that `minifyJS` also accepts a callback function though, and running the code explicitly through Terser that way works just fine:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.ejs',
    showErrors: isDevelopment,
    minify: isDevelopment ? false : {
        caseSensitive: false,
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: false,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: false,
        minifyJS: code => Terser.minify(code).code, // <-- call it manually
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
        sortAttributes: true,
        sortClassName: true,
    },
}),
```

Comment: Very interesting i am curious what the reason for this error is :)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Yeahhhh.... I am too, but not quite curious enough to debug this any further when such an easy workaround exists.